# ReactNativeJS: Can't find variable: Actions

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have used react-native-background-geolocation Plugin for background gps tracking but i frequently getting this error "Can't find variable: Actions"

although i am getting correct location object

i have used following code

```
BackgroundGeolocation.on('location', (location) => {
      //handle your locations here 
      console.log(JSON.stringify(location));
      Actions.sendLocation(location);
    });
```

it would be very helpfull for me if anyone have faced this issue ever or know how to solve !!

Comment: What is `Actions` exactly?

Comment: @martinarroyo frankly, i have lack of knowledge for react-native but it seems its part of react-native-background-geolocation Plugin.

Comment: Can you maybe post the code where you import it?

Comment: https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation

Comment: Mmm... I don't think that `Actions` is part of the package since it is not imported anywhere. I'd say that is just a placeholder for the sake of the example, and you have to replace it with your own custom code.

Comment: Yes i think its correct..@martinarroyo thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

Actions is apart of a package , so you must import it
For example

```
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
```

Comment: i didn't find anything related to sendLocation method,
i am seeing here : https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API_CONFIGURATION.md

could you please elaborate more that how it would be included with mentioned component(https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation)

Comment: sendLocation isn't a function related to 'react-native-router-flux' , it's a Scene name,  i.e it may be a page that receives location as a props.

Comment: yup but it's very simple 
define a Scene and attach it with a Component
create your Component.